# vba passing an array to a Dictionary.keys

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary

i have an array of strings `MyStrArray` and i have a dictionary object `MyDict`

**How** do I pass `MyStrArray` to `MyDict.keys` **Without looping**? is it possible?

if i try `MyDict.keys = MyStrArray` I get an error *"object Doesn't support this method"* and the keys bounds are `MyDict.Keys(0 to -1)`i know what that means and i know i can loop through the array to fill the dict. as such (simple example)

```
on error resume next 
    for i= Lbound(MyStrArray) To Ubound(MyStrArray)
    MyDict.add key:=MyStrArray(i), item:=whatever
    next i
```

so, is there a way around that??

Comment: well as far as I know, which isnt very much by the way, I think you would either need to loop or declare each array position for the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

the straight answer is "NO".

The following just in case you would consider a helper to just avoid looping in the main code

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim myDict As Dictionary

Dim myArr As Variant
myArr = Array("a", "b", "b")

Set myDict = GetDict(myArr)

End Sub


Function GetDict(keysArray As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(keysArray) To UBound(keysArray)
    dict.Add Key:=keysArray(i), Item:=i
Next i
Set GetDict = dict
End Function
```